# Change Source of Iframe from Vb Script

Tags: iframe, vbscript, getelementbyid

I need to be able to declare the source of Iframe from VBScript.Iframe is declared outside the Script

I frame Synatx:

```
<iframe  src ="" runat ="server" id="iframepdf" scrolling="auto"  align= "middle" 
marginheight="10px" width="1400px" height="700px"> 
</iframe>
```

My Code:-

```
<asp:Content ID="content" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" Runat="Server">
<td>
<iframe  src ="" runat ="server" id="iframepdf" scrolling="auto"  align= "middle"     
 marginheight="10px" width="1400px" height="700px"> 
 </iframe>
 </td>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
dim srcofiframe
</script>
```

I have tried Document.getElementById("Iframepdf").src=srcofiframe ->it did not work

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `src` attribute of the `<iframe>`:

```
Dim srcofiframe
srcofiframe = "http://www.example.com/"
document.getElementById("iframepdf").src = srcofiframe
```

Comment: @ Ansgr :I am getting this error when executing the above. 
I have declared the Iframe outside the Script .I need to send the source of iframe in the script.
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: 'Objectrequired: 'document.getElementByID(...)'

Answer (score 0):

If you work with JavaScript then .src is the way forward, however it errors when called within VBScript.  If you are programming a .vbs you you use:

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Navigate ""

My project was within a .hta, I applied the same logic:

iframepdf.Navigate ""

It worked a treat. Note I am calling that as a statement so there are no '()' required.